# How To Set ajax Run Every 5 Second

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

How To Set This ajax Run Every 5 Second

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var SrNo = document.getElementById('EntryType').value;
    var EntryType = document.getElementById('EntryType').value;
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "get_max_srno.php?CID=" + SrNo + "&EntryType=" + EntryType,
        data: {
            SrNo: $("#EntryType option:selected").val()
        },
        data: {
            EntryType: $("#EntryType option:selected").val()
        }
      })
      .done(function(msg1) {
          var msg = msg1;
          document.getElementById('SrNo').value = msg1;
      });
});
```

Comment: Have you tried googling?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
function autoCall(){
var feedback = $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "autocall.php",
    async: false
}).success(function(){
    setTimeout(function(){autoCall();}, 5000);
}).responseText; 
$('div').html(feedback);
}
```

if you want it to run only after successfully completing the call,

you can set it up in your .ajax().success() callback:

Or use .ajax().complete() if you want it to run regardless of result:

here is the demo explaining success() and complete(). 
here complete() will fire every 5 seconds as success is returning 404.

Hope this will be interesting everyone who looking this kind of problem.

[**Working Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/Iceburg/YXMPn/358/)

Comment: I think puttin into `success` callback can freeze the browser due the recursiveness

Answer (score 1):

You can use `setInterval` function.

For reference
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setInterval

```
var reloadContent = function () {

    var SrNo = document.getElementById('EntryType').value;
    var EntryType = document.getElementById('EntryType').value;

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "get_max_srno.php?CID=" + SrNo + "&EntryType=" + EntryType,
        data: {
            SrNo: $("#EntryType option:selected").val()
        },
        data: {
            EntryType: $("#EntryType option:selected").val()
        }
      })
      .done(function(msg1) {
          var msg = msg1;
          document.getElementById('SrNo').value = msg1;
      });

}

$(document).ready(function() {

    var reloadContentInterval = setInterval(reloadContent, 5000);

    // You can cancel it later if you want
    // clearInterval( reloadContentInterval );

});
```